# Possible typo in "FGA explained"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, quasicoherent-sheaves

In chapter 3 ("Fibred categories") of FGA explained (Fantechi et al.), there is an analysis of the fibred category of quasi-coherent sheaves. However, there seems to be, in my opinion, a typo regarding which quasi-coherent sheaf is on which scheme ("$\mathcal{N}$ on $U$ and $\mathcal{M}$ on $V$"):
[image]

Am I missing something here or is this really a typo ? My reasoning is that since the pushforward functor $f_{*}$ is a functor $\text{QCoh}(U) \rightarrow \text{QCoh}(V)$, it should not be able to act on $\mathcal{M}$, which is an object in $\text{QCoh}(V)$, and similarly for the pullback functor $f^{*}: \text{QCoh}(V) \rightarrow \text{QCoh}(U)$.

Comment: Seems like a typo, they also wrote $f^*N$ but $N$ is a sheaf on U, not on V.